# cflock/cfthread for auction closures

Tags: coldfusion

I'm building an auction site and I want to make sure that there are no issues with mutiple auctions closing at similar times. I have a basic understand of cflock and was wondering how this, or others like cfthread, could be applied optimally to protect this process from race conditions.

So far, my processing goes like this:

When an auction reaches its closing time, I initially set the status of "1" to indicate that the auction is closing. Site users then see the message "Closing" while the closure process takes place.

**close_auction.cfm**

```
<cfset resUpdateStatus = oListing.updateStatus(listing_id=url.listing_id, status=1)>
```

Then the call to the closeAuction() function:

```
<cfset resCloseAuction = oListing.closeAuction(listing_id=url.listing_id)>
```

**listing.cfc**

The closeAuction() function, with a cflock I'm currently using:

```
<cflock timeout="30" name="closeAuction_#arguments.listing_id#" type="exclusive">
     <cftransaction>
          <!--- if for whatever reason auction closure time not yet reached, delay a few seconds --->
          <cfloop condition = "now() lt qListing.end_date">
                <cfset oSystem.pause(TimeDelay=5)>                        
          </cfloop>
          <!--- processing here --->
          - select on listing table to ensure listing still exists
          - select on bids table - check high bid, determine if winner
          - update listing table - status, winner_id, close_date etc
          - update user_subscription table
          - delete scheduled task that auto-closes the auction
          - update tracking table
          - delete listing from users' watchlists
     </cftransaction>
</cflock>
```

This works fine while testing single auctions, but I'm concerned about what could happen under heavy load with many auctions closing potentially within seconds of each other. Any advice bullet-proofing this would be appreciated.

I'm on CF12

**UPDATE**

Updated to show processing inside cftransaction

Comment: Looks more complicated than necessary.  Simply comparing the current date and time to the date and time the auction ends might be all you need.  No locks, status codes, loops nor pauses required.

Comment: Adding a bunch of logic inside of a transaction is asking for trouble with your database.

Comment: Specifically, what "race conditions" do you think might occur?

Comment: @Dan, multiple auctions could end at exactly the same time, particularly as we are adding functionality to permit users to bulk-convert sale items into auctions, all with same start and end dates.

Comment: @JT I use the cftransaction to roll back all the various table updates if one of the updates fails. If there's a better way to do this, I want to know.

Comment: @Leigh, I may be worried about nothing and realise I don't need to lock anything that won't be adversely affected by a race condition. For auction closures, each closure only affects a single record so perhaps nothing to worry about, EXCEPT that someone may be trying to bid on that auction while it is in the closure process. The bid process itself is probably more prone to race conditions as a shared record is being updated by potentially many people.

Comment: Just a note: Apart from race conditions, I also want to make sure the process goes as quickly as possible under load. So, apart from streamlining the code, could cfthread by used perhaps? I have never used cfthread so any pointers would be great. Yes, I am reading the documentation.

Comment: Well a LOT depends on what is covered by "various tables updated". In general terms, it sounds like the sql should contain logic to only allow a particular record to be updated if it is in a specific state. In other words, let it be handled by normal database record locking. Typically that is accomplished with an additional filter. So instead of updating by id only, use something like `update tbl set state = 'closed' where id = 1 and state = 'open'`. Then check the record count. If it is 1, you know the update succeeded. Otherwise, it failed and you can take action from there.

Comment: *could cfthread by used perhaps* Honestly knowing very little about your app, I cannot say whether or not it would be beneficial. It can be a good tool when used correctly. However, it is not a miracle cure all ;-) Web apps are already multi-threaded and cfthread obviously adds more to the mix, increasing the likelihood that thread related logic flaws in the code will rear their ugly heads. Definitely read up on them to first get a better handle on what problems they *can* solve (and which ones they cannot) and the standard do's and don'ts with threading (proper scoping, locking, etcetera).

Comment: @Leigh There's quite a bit going on inside the cftransaction. I've updated the OP

Comment: Thanks. This is an interesting question, but it is very broad and still in the "it depends" realm ;-) Using a transaction guarantees [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29). That is not the same as an exclusive lock on the record(s), which is whole different kettle of fish. It really depends on *exactly* what the sql is doing and when (which is too much to cover in a single S.O. thread). Granted, I see the code is also using cflock as well, but .. I have zero experience using it with *database* queries.